# How to calculate differences between consecutive rows in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a data frame, `df`, with three columns: `count_a`, `count_b` and `date`; the counts are floats, and the dates are consecutive days in 2015.

I'm trying to figure out the difference between each day's counts in both the `count_a` and `count_b` columns — meaning, I'm trying to calculate the difference between each row and the preceding row for both of those columns. I've set the date as the index, but am having trouble figuring out how to do this; there were a couple of hints about using `pd.Series` and `pd.DataFrame.diff` but I haven't had any luck finding an applicable answer or set of instructions.

I'm a bit stuck, and would appreciate some guidance here.

Here's what my data frame looks like:

```
df=pd.Dataframe({'count_a': {Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): 34175.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-02 00:00:00'): 72640.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00'): 109354.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-04 00:00:00'): 144491.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-05 00:00:00'): 180355.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-06 00:00:00'): 214615.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-07 00:00:00'): 250096.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-08 00:00:00'): 287880.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-09 00:00:00'): 332528.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-10 00:00:00'): 381460.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-11 00:00:00'): 422981.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-12 00:00:00'): 463539.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-13 00:00:00'): 505395.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-14 00:00:00'): 549027.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-15 00:00:00'): 595377.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-16 00:00:00'): 649043.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-17 00:00:00'): 707727.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-18 00:00:00'): 761287.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-19 00:00:00'): 814372.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-20 00:00:00'): 867096.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-21 00:00:00'): 920838.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-22 00:00:00'): 983405.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-23 00:00:00'): 1067243.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-24 00:00:00'): 1164421.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-25 00:00:00'): 1252178.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-26 00:00:00'): 1341484.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-27 00:00:00'): 1427600.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-28 00:00:00'): 1511549.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-29 00:00:00'): 1594846.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-30 00:00:00'): 1694226.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-31 00:00:00'): 1806727.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00'): 1899880.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-02 00:00:00'): 1987978.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-03 00:00:00'): 2080338.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-04 00:00:00'): 2175775.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-05 00:00:00'): 2279525.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-06 00:00:00'): 2403306.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-07 00:00:00'): 2545696.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-08 00:00:00'): 2672464.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-09 00:00:00'): 2794788.0},
 'count_b': {Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-02 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-04 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-05 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-06 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-07 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-08 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-09 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-10 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-11 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-12 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-13 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-14 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-15 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-16 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-17 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-18 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-19 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-20 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-21 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-22 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-23 00:00:00'): nan,
  Timestamp('2015-01-24 00:00:00'): 71.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-25 00:00:00'): 150.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-26 00:00:00'): 236.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-27 00:00:00'): 345.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-28 00:00:00'): 1239.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-29 00:00:00'): 2228.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-30 00:00:00'): 7094.0,
  Timestamp('2015-01-31 00:00:00'): 16593.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00'): 27190.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-02 00:00:00'): 37519.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-03 00:00:00'): 49003.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-04 00:00:00'): 63323.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-05 00:00:00'): 79846.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-06 00:00:00'): 101568.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-07 00:00:00'): 127120.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-08 00:00:00'): 149955.0,
  Timestamp('2015-02-09 00:00:00'): 171440.0}})
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`diff` should give the desired result:

```
>>> df.diff()
count_a  count_b
2015-01-01      NaN      NaN
2015-01-02    38465      NaN
2015-01-03    36714      NaN
2015-01-04    35137      NaN
2015-01-05    35864      NaN
....
2015-02-07   142390    25552
2015-02-08   126768    22835
2015-02-09   122324    21485
```

Comment: also to add as new column in dataframe: `df['count_a_diff'] = df.count_a.diff()`

Comment: If a date is missing, how to have a NAN instead of subtracting 2 days?

Answer (score 27):

You can using the [`.rolling_apply(…)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments) method:

```
diffs_a = pd.rolling_apply(df['count_a'], 2, lambda x: x[0] - x[1])
```

Alternatively, if it's easier, you can operate on the arrays directly:

```
count_a_vals = df['count_a'].values
diffs_a = count_a_vals[:-1] - count_a_vals[1:]
```

Comment: rolling_apply doesn't exist anymore

Comment: It seems that the new way of doing it is to use [`Rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html).