# Python column difference

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a column that computes the difference between another column's elements:

```
Column A    Computed Column
10           blank  # nothing to compute for first record
9            1  # = 10-9
7            2  # = 9-7
4            3  # = 7-4
```

I am assuming this is a lambda function, but i am not sure how to reference the elements in 'Column A'

Any help/direction you can provide would be great- thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate differences between consecutive rows in pandas data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846146/how-to-calculate-differences-between-consecutive-rows-in-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: gaganso, you are right this is either a duplicate or very similar however the solution is different and works out better in my circumstance.  thank you- john

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by shifting the column.

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'A': [10,9,7,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)

df['Computed'] = df['A'].shift() - df['A']
print(df)
```

giving

```
    A  Computed
0  10       NaN
1   9       1.0
2   7       2.0
3   4       3.0
```

EDIT: OP extended his requirement to multi columns

```
dict1 = {'A': [10,9,7,4], 'B': [10,9,7,4], 'C': [10,9,7,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)

columns_to_update = ['A', 'B']
for col in columns_to_update:
    df['Computed'+col] = df[col].shift() - df[col]
print(df)
```

By using the columns_to_update, you can choose the columns you want.

```
    A   B   C  ComputedA  ComputedB
0  10  10  10        NaN        NaN
1   9   9   9        1.0        1.0
2   7   7   7        2.0        2.0
3   4   4   4        3.0        3.0
```

Comment: Spinor8, thank you for your response!  Quick follow up question, is there a way to treat Column A as a variable.  In this instance I used 4 numbers, but in reality my dataset has 2k+ elements in length.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes. Iterate through the columns of interest. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Actually, and I apologize for this, but your first answer correctly answered my inquiry.  I was thrown off by the usage of the dictionary when you created a new dataframe.  I incorrectly thought that in order to complete the function you had to utilize a dictionary, but after reviewing what you proposed, it made sense.  Children(sleep deprivation) + wine != good proof reading

Comment: If only pandas wasnt so darn optimized! This method on a DataFrame with a column of size 10K completes in 0.00317 seconds whereas mine completes in 0.00319. Excellent use of optimized classes @Spinor8.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[10,9,7,4], columns=['A'])
df['B'] = abs(df['A'].diff())
```

The reason for `abs()` is because `diff()` computes the difference between `current - previous` whereas you want `previous - current`. This method is already built-in to the `Series` class, so using `abs()` will get you the correct result by taking the absolute value either way.

To support:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[10,9,7,4], columns=['A'])
df['B'] = abs(df['A'].diff())
>>> df
# Output
    A    B
0  10  NaN
1   9  1.0
2   7  2.0
3   4  3.0
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[10,4,7,9], columns=['A'])
df2['B'] = abs(df2['A'].diff())
>>> df2
# Output
    A    B
0  10  NaN
1   4  6.0
2   7  3.0
3   9  2.0
```

To still out perform that of @cosmic_inquiry's solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[10,9,7,4], columns=['A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[10,4,7,9], columns=['A'])
df['B'] = df['A'].diff() * -1
df2['B'] = df2['A'].diff() * -1
>>> df
# Output:
    A    B
0  10  NaN
1   9  1.0
2   7  2.0
3   4  3.0
>>> df2
# Output:
    A    B
0  10  NaN
1   4  6.0
2   7 -3.0
3   9 -2.0
```

Comment: Won't work if you have `df = pd.DataFrame(data=[10,4,7,9], columns=['A'])`

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry How do you figure that?

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry No, the difference between two numbers is always the absolute value between the two. I don't think you understand the mathematical principle at play here.

Comment: Mate your thinking of "distance". The "difference" is the result of subtracting two numbers or expressions. Literally did not think I would have to go to a sixth grade website to resolve this but here ya go: http://www.uzinggo.com/subtraction-integers/whole-numbers-integers/math-foundations-grade-6

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry Difference and distance are synonyms; thus the delta or rate of change between two numbers. Either way you try to spin this, mathematically you are categorically incorrect. If I decrease speed from 4 to 7, I have decreased my speed by 3, not by -3. This simple understanding is applied in far greater context then shown here.

Comment: They are not synonyms at all. In the formula you posted to calculate the **distance** between coordinate points they take the **difference** between basis components of the two points (then square, sum, and square root). It would be correct to say that difference and subtraction are synonyms. "If I decrease speed from 4 to 7", no one would ever say that. You would say "If I increase speed from 4 to 7" indicating a positive change...

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry You clearly didnt bother to read down further to One Dimension...

Comment: "The distance between any two points on the real line is the absolute value of the numerical difference of their coordinates." Hopefully this is what you're referring to... So let me tell you what this isn't saying:

"The distance between any two points on the real line is the difference of their coordinates." 

... which is exactly how you are interpreting. **Distance** and **difference** are **not** the same. One describes the length between two points, the other is a mathematical operation synonymous with subtraction.

Comment: You quoted it here yourself so thanks for proving me right!  "The **distance** between any two points on the real line **is the difference** of their coordinates."  Complete a few higher level mathematics courses and you'll understand one day young padawan.

Comment: **So let me tell you what this isn't saying** **ISN'T**

Comment: **IS NOT SAYING**

Comment: You're just going to get reported and modded you know that right? You've provided nothing factual to build upon your conclusion and now you're just spamming comments with probably your 3rd or 4th account since you keep getting banned from asking questions of proper caliber.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176499/discussion-between-pstatix-and-cosmic-inquiry).

Answer (score 0):

Use [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[10,9,7,4], columns=['A'])
df['B'] = df.A.diff(-1).shift(1)
```

Output:

```
df
Out[140]: 
    A    B
0  10  NaN
1   9  1.0
2   7  2.0
3   4  3.0
```

Comment: Taking the absolute value of the `diff()` requires less operations.

Comment: You can only use the absolute value of the data is monotonically decreasing

Comment: Thats completely false...otherwise all Euclidean space geometry is incorrect and you have just developed a game changing mathematically way of detecting the distance between two points in `R^n` space. Its going to be revolutionary!

Comment: I'll leave [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) here for you to do some reading. Notice that the power of 2 is applied since XY points reside in `R^2` space. However, single values like that of the OP reside in `R^1` space. The distance between two points along the number line is simply the count between the two points in either direction. For ease, jump down to the One Dimension section.

Comment: damn I must get like a nobel prize or someting

Comment: Hardly, never-the-less I even show the same solution that upholds the mathematical principle and gives you the desired output you believe the OP wants.