# How to do substruction in the cells of columns in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

> > I have this dataframe (df) in python:

```
  Cumulative sales
0        12
1        28
2        56
3        87
```

> > I want to create a new column in which I whould have the the number of new sales (N-(N-1)) as below:

```
  Cumulative sales   New Sales
0        12             12
1        28             16
2        56             28
3        87             31
```

Comment: this is dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114512/calculating-difference-between-two-rows-in-python-pandas) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846146/how-to-calculate-differences-between-consecutive-rows-in-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating difference between two rows in Python / Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114512/calculating-difference-between-two-rows-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @Ben.T it worked! thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
df['new sale']=df.Cumulativesales.diff().fillna(df.Cumulativesales)
df
   Cumulativesales  new sale
0               12      12.0
1               28      16.0
2               56      28.0
3               87      31.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
df['New_sales'] = df['Cumlative_sales'].diff()
df.fillna(df.iloc[0]['Cumlative_sales'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Cumlative_sales  New_sales
0               12       12.0
1               28       16.0
2               56       28.0
3               87       31.0
```